# Dynamically updatable buttons for Phone calls using App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

My road safety app has an `emergency numbers` section wherein I have laid out a horizontal arrangement with a button and a list picker for Police, Fire, Traffic etc.

[This](http://tinypic.com/r/2gw9oc4/8) is how it is intended to look like. My question is

**Can the call button be dynamically updated to make calls to different numbers using the MakePhoneCall method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, just set the phone number before doing the call...

> PhoneCall1.PhoneNumber = 1234567890 
>   PhoneCall1.MakePhoneCall

However you might have another problem, [see this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/programming-with-app-inventor/emergency%2420call/programming-with-app-inventor/lrymsAkCepA/o2QTowFfHBsJ). But [this might be a solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/programming-with-app-inventor/emergency%2420call/programming-with-app-inventor/E3Cjk9KtUSw/ZliQplUo_gIJ) for you...

Comment: Thanks dude. Really appreciate your constant guidance! :)
I'll just put a notifier or a label in case the auto dialer doesn't allow me to call 3 digit numbers.